# Why are my webpack 5 imports not resolving for Typescript in my React 18 project?

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-5

When running my React 18 + Typescript + Webpack 5 project, I get

```
export 'setStore' (imported as 'setStore') was not found in 'components-folder' (possible exports: ChevronLeft, FilterIcon, UpdateTableIcon, styled, variant, withTheme)
 @ ./src/index.tsx 7:0-38 12:9-14
```

The issue is that in the components folder, the desired `setStore` does exist:

```
export const setStore = (store: any) => {
  // @ts-expect-error ts-migrate(2339) FIXME: Property 'REDUX_STORE' does not exist on type 'Doc... Remove this comment to see the full error message
  document.REDUX_STORE = store
}
```

`components-folder` is a collection of React based components I also maintain and that I therefore import as

```
"components-folder": "git+ssh://git@github.com:me/components-folder.git",
```

in my `package.json` dependencies.

In my project, I used to access it as:

```
import { getAllBlockModels, setStore } from 'components-folder'
```

It may be important to note that in webpack 4 this worked. Also, if I give it the exact (i.e `import { setStore } from 'components-folder/path/to/setStore` it also works). Additionally, I see that this also happens for my cherry picked lodash imports, things like: `import get from 'lodash/get`.

My webpack config includes

```
alias: {
  
      'components-folder': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../components-folder'),
      
    },
```

I have tried changes to `tsconfig` including `paths`, `typeRoots` and everything the internet has to offer. I also tried custom loaders.

Worth noting that it happens on both my dev server and when I try to build